# Cross-domain HTTPS resource access

Tags: web, https, cross-domain

I know that if you access an HTTP resource within an HTTPs page, most browsers will warn you.  Are there any issues regarding loading a resource across HTTPS from foo.com when the page is served on bar.com?

For example, assume the following page comes from https://www.bar.com/index.html:

```
<html>
<script src="https://somescript.foo.com/foo.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no issues.

This is common practice in PayPal shopping carts, where PayPal includes the user's logo from a 3rd party site via https://